# Best type to store a LINQ result in a global variable

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm writing a report and loading the data to display as soon as the report loads using LINQ.

```
summaryData = from summary in _entity.Summary
              // some constraints here
              select new
              {
                  summary.payment_category_desc,
                  summary.payment_due_amt,
                  summary.currency_desc
              };
```

I need to consume these results later in a different event(the PrintDetail), in a way that I can , for instance, say:

```
string name = summaryData[currentIndex].payment_category_desc
```

Basically what I need is to find how to store the LINQ results in a global variable that I can later enumerate. I've tried IQueriable and it wont let me. I'm also trying to avoid having to create a class with three members in order to be able to use ToList().

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you consider creating a class that contains those three variables and then store the results in a "global" list?

Comment: Dont't really understand your poit. The result of LINQ is already enumerator so you can enumerate.

Comment: @Tigran I guess the problem is that he wants to enumerate in an event at a later time, but he can't cause he is creating an anonymous type so he can't access the variables. That's my take at the question.

Comment: Thats exactly what it is Petak. I was trying to avoid a new class just for that. Do you think thats the best approach?

Comment: @allendehl If you want to use the results in any other scope than the scope in which they are produced, it would (IMHO) be the only way. Of course, something could be done using reflection (or .NET 4 dynamic), but that would require a lot more code than what a simple class requires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** To be honest, I only just noticed that you were using an anonymous types. As you already know by now, there is no way you can get an anon-type outside your method. However, you can use a C# 4.0 Tuple<>

The following will work when summaryData is passed/defined outside you current method:

```
summaryData = from summary in _entity.Summary
          // some constraints here
          select new Tuple<string, DateTime, decimal>
          {
              summary.payment_category_desc,
              summary.payment_due_amt,
              summary.currency_desc
          };
```

---

Whatever it is, if it is a collection/query result, `IEnumerable<T>` will work

Be sure to think whether you need to convert to a list (cache the result) with `.ToList()` first.
If you don't the original enumerator will get executed multiple times, which could be a (performance) issue. Consider when the enumerator accesses a file that is not longer opened, accessible etc.

Comment: If I'm right in order to use ToList() I'd need to create a class to hold the results so I can declare summaryData of List<myClass> type.
I was trying to avoid this..unless it is my best choice.

Comment: It would be easier to use `Tuple.Create(...)`, which will infer the type arguments, so you don't have to repeat `<string, DateTime, decimal>`.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd avoid using a global variable. You make it harder to test your application when you have a dependency such as a global variable.

I don't know your exact architecture but I'd be tempted to pass the object to the relevant methods that require it. At least this way you can easily mock your object and you reduce the dependency.

Comment: Basically I'm loading the data in the report "BeforePrint" event, then I need to consume it in the detail "BeforePrint" event, where I have to index it to iterate through all the results.

Answer (score 1):

Your IQueryable result employs deffered execution. If you are coding that inside of a "using" block, you won't have a connection when you try to access your results (global variable or not).

Try returning a List from your LINQ query via the ToList() extension method.